# How do i write code to the code section of a sheet at runtime

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write code into the code section of a worksheet at runtime.

I am importing data using the "TEXT" data connection and this process writes to a new sheet. I would like to write data validation code to the worksheet to fire whenever end users change data on the sheet.

For greater clarity: I would like to insert a text file, which contains validation code, into the code section of a worksheet. 
I was able to figure out how to write code to a sheet code module as follows:

```
Sub CreateProc_Code()
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Set VBComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet11")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    CodeMod.AddFromFile ("C:\Users\Richard Mertl\Desktop\sheetcode.txt")
End Sub
```

But, I am looking how to embed this into the file without having to refer to an external file.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: I have resolved the issue by saving the VBA code to a sheet and then loading the code from a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can import VBA modules at runtime via VBA as well as manually.  See:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not resolve the issue that I want to import/insert VB code in a worksheet's code section at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` change event.

Below is sample code. If any value in row 2 changes msgbox will be called. You can write the validation code here.

Put the code in sheet code section.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 On Error GoTo err_rout


    Application.EnableEvents = False


    If Target.Row = 2 Then

        MsgBox "something changed"

    End If


err_rout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I need to be able to import/insert the VB code into this section at run time.